# Como redirigir el foco al inicio de la pagina después de seleccionar una opción en una LOV?

Tags: apex

Tengo una pagina de gráficos en una aplicación apex 5.0 y cada uno se basa en una lov para seleccionar el tipo de gráfico, pero al hacer la selección de una opción al refrescar me dirige al  inicio de la pagina, y claro cambia el gráfico, pero quiero que se quede el foco en la región donde esta el gráfico. y que al salir y volver a entrar a la pagina el foco entre al inicio de la pagina y no en la región del gráfico. eso es lo que me esta sucediendo.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto la mejor opción es utilizar Acciones Dinámicas para que la página no se tenga que refrescar completamente.
En vez de hacer submit a la página cuando la LOV cambie de valor, crea una Acción Dinámica que refresque / muestre el gráfico correspondiente.